# How do i get a reference clip to start playing later in the timeline?

Tags: animation, timeline

I am still learning how to use blender and am using reference clips for different actions throughout a single animation. The reference clip i want to use to animate my final action ends long before i get to the start frame for the animation. inserting the clip always seems to default the beginning of the clip to the first frame of the timeline.

Vers. 2.79, Cycles Render.
[image: Anthro Fox sculpt assignment]

Comment: Please show some of your work as a Blender Screen capture in this and all future questions to clarify you question.  Please indicate which renderer, Cycles, Blender Internal ... you are using expliclity and via screen captures.

Comment: Do not expect the readers to guess even though they might make a reasonable guess.  Version of  Blender 2.7 ... 2.8?